# PHP Exploding string with 3 variables

Tags: php, regex

I have this string:

```
132(250-1,4.50).133(750-1,6.50).134(650-1,7.50).135(550-1,8.50)
```

The "." defines a new "object".

Using the first "object" as an example, I wish to explode each value into arrays like so:

```
arrayids[] = 132;
arrayweight[132] => 250;
arraymeasur[132] => 1;
arrayprices[132] => 4.50;
```

The period simply defines a new object.

I have tried using str_pos and other such php functions to find a solution and I simply do not understand regex - can anybody help me solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want 4 different arrays? You can just create 1 array with `132` as the key from a new array which contains the values.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, regardless however that is not the problem I have - the problem I have is getting the data from the monstrously long string of objects - I don't understand how to extract them. I have exploded 2 values at most.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that hard you just need alot of `explodes`:

```
<?php
$newArray = [];
$string = "132(250-1,4.50).133(750-1,6.50).134(650-1,7.50).135(550-1,8.50)";
$explString = explode(").", $string);

foreach($explString as $exStr){
  $explSubstr = explode("(", $exStr);

  $explFirst = explode("-", $explSubstr[1]);    
  $explRest = explode(",", $explFirst[1]);  

  $newArray[$explSubstr[0]] = [
      "weight" => $explFirst[0],
      "measure" => $explRest[0],
      "prices" => $explRest[1]
  ];
}

var_dump($newArray);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Couldn't see the wood for the trees.

Comment: @Daan, it doesn't work for me. [135][ 'prices'] =  "8.50)". Also you didn't follow the structure in the question.

Comment: @Axalix I recommended a better structure in the comments and he agreed that's why I did this structure.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$arrayids = $arrayweight = $arrayprices = [];

$str = '132(250-1,4.50).133(750-1,6.50).134(650-1,7.50).135(550-1,8.50)';

array_walk(explode(').', $str), function($segment) use (&$arrayids, &$arrayweight, &$arraymeasur, &$arrayprices) {
    if (preg_match('/^([0-9\.]+)\(([0-9\.]+)-([0-9\.]+),([0-9\.]+)/', $segment, $matches)) {
        $key = $matches[1];
        list(, $arrayids[], $arrayweight[$key], $arraymeasur[$key], $arrayprices[$key]) = $matches;
    }
});

var_dump($arrayids);
var_dump($arrayweight);
var_dump($arraymeasur);
var_dump($arrayprices);
```